# Why following code printing False?

Tags: java

Replace will create new object and both side this new will be compared. then why it showing false.

When exactly created new string will be added in string pool?

```
if("String".replace("g", "G") == "String".replace("g", "G"))
{
    System.out.println("True");    
} else {
    System.out.println("False"); 
}
```

Comment: I thought of marking it as duplicate :).. Not sure whether we have an *exact* duplicate here. I think the OP wants to know whether the `replace` operation gives same string from constants pool or creates a new one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because `replace()` will always return a *new* String instance. So the 2 *same* calls to replace method will return 2 different instances with same value.

1. use `equals()` instead of `==` if you want to compare *value*
2. Use `intern()` on both replaced values if you want to add the string to the *string constants pool* (and are bent on using `==` :P)

   ```
   if ("String".replace("g", "G").intern() == "String".replace("g", "G").intern()) {
       System.out.println("True");
   } else {
       System.out.println("False");
   }
   ```

   }

OP :

```
true
```

Comment: Where is it created ? , In Heap or String pool ?  I need to used equal only if they are in heap. If they are in string pool then  == should work.

Comment: @PiyushAghera - always remember --> Only *interned* strings and *String literals* go into the String constants pool. All other strings created from operations like `replace()`, `substring()` etc go into the `heap`. It is worth noting that *The String constants pool* is part of the *heap* :)

Comment: @PiyushAghera "If they are in string pool then == should work" which proves that instance created and returned by `replace` is not interned and doesn't come from string pool.